# htaccess 301 redirect into a rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I know this must have an answer somewhere around here, but I am unable to find/locate it.

There is a typical 301 redirection rule in the same domain:

```
Redirect 301 /path/to/strange-url.htm /path/to/new/canonical-url.htm
```

Later on htaccess file, there is a rewrite rule for the canonical-url

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)([^/]+)/([^-]+)-([^.]+)\.htm$ php/page.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4&var5=$5 [NC,L]
```

Problem is that as soon as the 301 redirect activates, my new url becomes:

```
/path/to/new/canonical-url.htm?var1=xxxx&var2=xxxx&var3=xxxx&var4=xxxx&var5=xxxx
```

How can I avoid this and maintain only the clean url: `/path/to/new/canonical-url.htm` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i finally found a working solution

I changed all Redirect 301 rules to RewriteRule [R=301,L], so:

```
Redirect 301 /path/to/strange-url.htm /path/to/new/canonical-url.htm
```

becomes

```
RewriteRule ^/path/to/strange-url.htm http://www.example.com/path/to/new/canonical-url.htm [R=301,L]
```

Also, I have moved all former redirects before the actual rewrites

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have a loop, try to add condition on requested URI, like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^php/page.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)([^/]+)/([^-]+)-([^.]+)\.htm?$ php/page.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4&var5=$5 [NC,L]
```

Comment: nope, this didn't work. I still get the query string at the end of redirected url

Comment: Can you provide full content of .htaccess file?

Comment: i'd rather not... its way too long list of rules (more than 250k). The 301 redirects i mention are 540 rules (old crappy html pages), to be rewritten under one new pattern